# Pattern binding operator on assignment

Tags: regex, perl

I am working into uncommented perl code. I came across a passage, that looks too perl-ish to me as a perl beginner. This is a simplified adaption:

```
my $foo;
my $bar = "x|y|z|";

$bar =~ s{\|$}{};
($foo = $bar) =~ s{ }{}gs;
```

I understand that `$bar =~ s{\|$}{}` applies the regular expression on the right to the string inside `$bar`.
But what does the expression `($foo = $bar) =~ s{ }{}gs;` mean? I am not asking about the regular expression but on the expression it is apllied to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just follow the precedence that the parentheses dictate and solve each statement one at the time:

```
($a = $b) =~ s{ }{}gs;
#^^^^^^^^--- executed first
($a = $b)        # set $a to the value contained in $b
$a =~ s{ }{}gs;  # perform the regex on $a
```

The `/g` global modifier causes the regex to match as many times as possible, the `/s` modifier makes the wildcard `.` match newline as well (so it now really matches everything). The `/s` modifier is redundant for this regex, since there are no wildcards `.` in it.

Note that `$a` and `$b` are predeclared variables which are used by `sort`, and you should avoid using them.

When in doubt, you can always print the variables and see how they change. For example:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $x = 'foo bar';
(my $y = $x) =~ s{ }{}gs;
print Dumper $x, $y;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = 'foo bar';
$VAR2 = 'foobar';
```

Comment: Thanks. Spoiled by profound answers on SO like this one I did not expect to actually find out much about what is acutally going on with the variables by just observing how they change. A collegue of mine guessed "the regex is performed on `$b` but the result is stored in `$a`" which would result in the same values but I would not know now, that `$b` was assigned to `$a` in between.

Comment: It is interesting that `$b` (or `$x`) remains unchanged. However, this is a sort of Perl magic that is never really necessary to use. I think it is much more readable to just divide the statement in two.

Comment: Good point about `$a` and `$b` as "reserved" variables. In this case I just renamed the actual variables for the example.

Comment: I accepted Yours because of the example You provided. Interested users should read ikegami's answer regarding the syntax related to the r-flag.

Comment: I know about the `/r` modifier, but it requires Perl v5.14, and while practical, it is only a convenience. Also it is somewhat obscure, and many people may miss it and be confused.

Comment: Re "I would not know now, that $b was assigned to $a in between", (4+5)*6 obviously does the addition before the multiplication. Same here.

Answer (score 4):

A scalar assignment in scalar context returns its left-hand-side operand (as shown [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129)). That means

```
$a = $b
```

assigns the value of `$b` to `$a` and returns `$a`. That means

```
($a = $b) =~ s{ }{}gs;
```

is short for

```
$a = $b; $a =~ s{ }{}gs;
```

and long for

```
$a = $b =~ s{ }{}gsr;  # Requires 5.14+
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the new r-flag to me in `$a = $b =~ s{ }{}gsr;`

Answer (score 1):

> But what does the expression ($a = $b) =~ s{ }{}gs; mean?

It is same as

```
$a = $b;
$a =~ s{ }{}gs;
```

`s{ }{}gs` is substitution `s/ //gs` regex with `{}` as delimiters